# Ordering records that start with a parenthesis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, special-characters

Say I have a bunch of records in my database that all have a title, soms which can start with a special character.

```
records = Record.find(:all, :order => :title)
records.map{|record| record.title}
#=> ["(Ccc)", "Aaa", "Bbb", "Ddd", "_Eee_"]
```

Underscores come last, but parentheses apparently are treated differently and come first. How do I go about ordering these so that the records starting with a parenthesis are at the end as well?

```
#=> ["Aaa", "Bbb", "Ddd", "(Ccc)", "_Eee_"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to implement a collation which orders parentheses in the desired order. This is database-specific; for example, [this chapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation.html) describes how to do it in MySQL. This requires some effort, but will not incur any penalties to your application, neither in execution time nor in storage space.

An inferior way would be to do it in Ruby: pull all records, then resort using a custom function. The bad thing about it is you lose the ability to do pagination through the database interface, since you need the complete set in Ruby to be able to resort.

A middle (and probably the easiest) way would be to create an additional column which transforms your titles so that the default collation sorts them correctly, then order the titles by that column instead. For example, if you have `Aaa, Bbb, Ddd, _(Ccc_), __Eee__` as your title order column (i.e. escape underscores and parentheses with an additional underscore), the sorting should be correct.